# Include external file in XBAP application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, vb.net, xbap

How can i include an external file in a XBAP application? For example a .dat file where i need to extract some data from? I want everything to happen inside the .xbap file, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] ba = Properties.Resources.yourfilename;
//set  Build Action to Resource and Rebuild 
using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(ba))
using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
    ba1 = resultStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the .dat as a resource to the project
then during runtime extract using a stream and save to a file on temp folder